# How I can show the backdrop when popover appeared and backdrop disappeared when popover disappeared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How I can show the backdrop when **popover appeared** and backdrop disappeared when **popover disappeared**?

```js
$(function(){
  var content = '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="location.href=\'/billing/\'">Pay Now</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-default " onclick="$(&quot;.btn-upgrade-premium&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">Activation Code</button>';
  $('.btn-upgrade-premium').popover({animation:true, content:content, html:true, placement: 'bottom'});
  $('.btn-upgrade-premium').click(function(){
    $('#backdrop').toggleClass('modal-backdrop in');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-upgrade-premium
{
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFEEBE 0%, #fec215 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #fec215;
  z-index: 1052;
}
.btn-upgrade-premium:active
{
  background-color: #fec215;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-upgrade-premium btn-sm" style="margin-top:11px; padding-bottom:4px; padding-top:4px;" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus"  data-placement="left">
  Upgrade to Premium
</button>
<div id="backdrop"></div>
```

**NOTE:**

My problem is the backdrop won't disappeared even I toggled the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `position: relative;` to the button CSS style `.btn-group-sm>.btn, .btn-sm`. Button is being covered by `#backdrop` which is why you can't click it.

If you want to keep the button covered then you may add the same toggle function to the backdrop.

The problem is because of how **fixed** elements (backdrop) relate to **static** elements. Since you didn't set a **position** value for the button, it's default will be `static`, so setting it to **relative** will sort the issue. Also pay attention to **z-index**, but in this case **z-index** is already set.

Comment: How I also can remove backdrop when user click anywhere on the screen like popover disappear? I mean not just when the `upgrade premium` button clicked.

Comment: Brilliant!! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

read the article

https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

My Jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/davygxyz/ffezrxL5/

I would check to see if this will still work with extra javascript, for now it works.

add this to your code

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
          if (!$(event.target).closest('.btn-upgrade-premium').length) {
            $('#backdrop').toggleClass('modal-backdrop in');
          }
    });
```